# Protractor: Trying to check if an Element is not displayed on page ( using .count() )

Tags: node.js, protractor, aurelia, e2e-testing

I originally had this working but I've started using Gulp and Lint so now I need to change how I approach this.
I'm checking to see if a user has a single currency displaying or multiple currencies. If a user only has one currency (e.g "EUR") then a div called 
`"nav-tabs au-target" show.bind="positions.length > 1" au-target-id="37"` will **not** be displayed on the page.

This is the code from page object file

```js
if(text.indexOf("EUR") >-1 && text.indexOf("GBP") ===-1 && text.indexOf("USD") ===-1){
expect(element(by.css("nav-tabs au-target")).count()).toBe(0);}
```

Basically it's checking if"EUR" is only displayed then expect `"div nav-tabs au-target"` not to be present.
When I run this code, I get the following error 
    `Failed: element(...).count is not a function`
Thanks for any help

Comment: count() will be applicable to element.all()(ElementFinders). in your case your applied for single element(). That is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for that!

Comment: You can also use `$$("nav-tabs au-target").count()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.count()` method on the `ElementFinder` instance (result of `element()`). [`count()` is a method of an `ElementArrayFinder` instance](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count) (result of `element.all()`).

Note that if you would've used [`ESLint` JavaScript linter](http://eslint.org/) with the [`eslint-plugin-protractor` plugin](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) (shameless self-promotion), you could've caught the problem earlier - during coding, without actually executing tests:

[image]